# IPC Android Injection

Tags: java, android, ipc, code-injection

Can you tell me how to use IPC Injection?

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String view;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_main2 );
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        view = bundle.getString( "view" );
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.t1 );
        text.setText( view );

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(runnable1  );
        thread1.start();
    }

    Runnable runnable1 = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep( 5000 );
                Log.d( "IPC TEST","進入了1" );

                view = "https://" + view;

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse( view ));
                startActivity(intent);
                Log.d( "IPC TEST","進入了2" );
            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.d( "IPC TEST",e.toString() );
            }
        }
    };

}
```

How to make an `intent` import do not know the activity?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse( view ));
startActivity(intent);
```

please tell me.

Comment: It would be helpful if you post the error you are getting and what is it that you are trying to acheive

Comment: Already build.
Can import other websites.
But I want to know how to import the activity class.

Comment: Or what value is injection into the "view", causing the import of other activity classes.